# Android studio Ctrl hotkeys does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, hotkeys

For some reasons <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in my Android studio does not work, so I cannot use the most of hot keys.

How can I make it working?

The OS is Fedora 20.

Comment: using windows 8.1 and not working too...

Comment: @mehmet6parmak they released stable version two weeks ago, try to update. That worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to stable version has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

settings > keymap> default

I had the same issue, for some reason I found that keymap settings are set to mac OS.

I am running a PC so I changed the keymap to default and this fixed the issue for me. 
Hope this helps.

[settings: key map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRes9.jpg)